# Jaxb2 regenerate classes with every mvn clean package

Tags: maven, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

My pom looks like

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.xsd</include>
                    <include>draw/*.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

When I do a `mvn clean package` it is built according to the configuration. However after I have built it once I don't want to build it every time I do a `mvn clean package` unless the `XSD` has been modified somehow.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Generating into `src/main/java` is in general a bad idea...

Comment: you are right... I have fixed this thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default phase declared in this plugin for the goal `<goal>generate</goal>` is `generate-resources`. referring to Maven Default Lifecycle you can't skip phases. The mvn phase-x command always means "run all phases until phase-x, inclusive".

The option you may use is `profile`. so you can profile your project to be build with or without generating resources.

Example:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>GEN-RESOURCES</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.12.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>*.xsd</include>
                            <include>draw/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

to activate the profile use -P

```
mvn clean package -PGEN-RESOURCES
```

otherwise no thing will be generated
Maven profile explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: While this would work, this is not the right direction. First, the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` has a built-in feature to regenerate only if schemas changed. Next, using profiles to turn on and off build steps will result in terrible build files. Therefore the downvote, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

First, do not generate into `src/main/java`.

Next, if configured correctly, the plugin *will not* regenerate *unless* something changes. The plugin gathers "source" and "target" files and generates if and only if timestamp of "source" file is newer that of the "target" files.

See [Up-to-Date Checks](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Up-To-Date-Checks) in the documentation for more information on how it works.

This, however, assumes that the plugin can cleanly determine timestamps of both "source" and "target" files. This is one of the reasons why you should generate your code into `target/generated-source/<dir>` and not in `src/main/java`.

Next, this definitely does not work with `mvn *clean* package` as `*clean*` removes `target` and therefore `target/generated-source/<dir>`. So just run `mvn package` instead of `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Thank you I have changed from src/main/java and indeed it works as you described. When I do not use clean it does not build.